# Determining $g(-i)$ for $g(z) = \ln(1-z^2)$, given that $g(i) = \ln(2)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

> Consider $g(z) = \ln(1-z^2)$ defined on $C$ \ $(-\infty, 1]$. Find $g(-i)$ given that $g(i) = \ln(2)$.

I've begun by stating $\ln(1-z^2) = \ln|1-z^2| + i*arg(1-z^2)$.

The real part at $g(-i) = \ln(2)$

To evaluate the argument at $g(-i)$:

$arg(1-z^2) = arg(1-z^2) + \Delta arg(1-z^2)$

where $\Delta arg$ is the change in argument as we travel from $i$ to $-i$ around the branch cut.

$arg(1-z^2) = 0$ because it's only real at $-i$.

I split $\Delta arg(1-z^2) = \Delta arg(1-z) + \Delta arg(1+z)$

I obtained $-2\pi$ after evaluating the above.

So $g(-i) = \ln(2) - 2\pi i$

I cannot obtain the same solution trying to evaluate just $\Delta arg(1-z^2)$. Is it because I do not have the correct solution above? I find that the change in argument is 0. Am I missing something important?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you see that you can write $g(z)=\log(2)+\int_i^z\frac{2w\,\mathrm{d}w}{w^2-1}$ ?

Comment: @robjohn I am not familiar yet with complex integration. So far I have just evaluated the change in argument as I travel to $g(-i)$ as shown in my edit.

Comment: I don't understand. $g(z) = g(-z)$ for any $z$ such that $z$ and $-z$ are in the domain of $g$.

Comment: @hunter: that is not the case here. The answer is indeed $g(-i)=\log(2)-2\pi i$ as jmb states.

Comment: @robjohn perhaps I don't understand the notation. By definition, $g(z) = \ln(1-z^2)$. No matter which branch of the logarithm is chosen, this still only depends on $z^2$.

Comment: @hunter: if you follow $g(z)=\log\left(1-z^2\right)$ from $z=i$ to $z=\sqrt3$ to $z=-i$, you will see that $g(z)$ goes from $\log(2)$ to $\log(2)-\pi i$ to $\log(2)-2\pi i$. $\log(z)$ traces out a [Riemann Surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface#/media/File:Riemann_surface_log.svg), and so moving from $z=i$ to $z=-i$ will move down the helix one level (decreasing the imaginary part by $2\pi i$).

Comment: @jmb: the fact that $1-z^2$ circles $1$ twice while $z$ circles $0$ once, means that $\log\left(1-z^2\right)$ takes values in two branches of $\log$ in a sliced neighborhood of $1$.